# How to pass a dictionary of arguments as a spider argument in Scrapy?

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler, scrapy-shell

scrapy crawl link -a '{"urls":"https://www.xyz.in","contains":"hello","Xpath":"hiii" }'

Comment: Prepend the variable name (`-a 'variable_name={…}'`) and then access the variable from your spider (`self.variable_name`) and parse it from JSON into a Python dict (`json.loads(self.variable_name)`)

Answer (score 0):

first you need to be call a variable for the pass argument in Dictionary. Here I am assuming you want to scrape the url from this Dictionary.

```
url_Scraper = {"urls":"https://www.xyz.in","contains":"hello","Xpath":"hiii" }

print(url_scraper["urls"])
```

You can get any specific element from Dictionary. You just need to be put specific dictionary key within square brackets after variable. For better understand see the second example.Assuming you want to get "hiii" from xpath

```
xpath_Scraper = {"urls":"https://www.xyz.in","contains":"hello","Xpath":"hiii" }

print(url_scraper["Xpath"])
```

Comment: scrapy crawl link -a config="{"urls":"https://www.colive.in","contains":"hello","Xpath":"hiii"}"     
.In the __init__ function, the value is coming as a single string.     config= {urls:https://www.xyz.in,contains:hello,Xpath:hiii } .  how to convert it into dictionary.